# Modifying an Org table using elisp?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-table

Currently I have two org tables, and want to use the data stored in both of them to change the second table. Reading the tables in a source block is no problem, but what do I have to do to write fields of a table?

Comment: I know this is old, but [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18135/how-to-programmatically-update-a-named-org-table-in-situ) is a similar question.